# Using javascript variable in html?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, drop-down-menu

```
<select STYLE="font-size:55%; width: 100px;" class="inpSelect" name="sel2" id="region2" onchange="setIframeSource2()">
          <option value="url1.com">Start Date</option> 
          <option value="url2.com">Account Name (A-Z)</option> 
     </select>
```

How can I use a javascript variable inside the `value` attribute? Is it possible?

Comment: what kind of variable ? Javscript variable ? PHP or similar server-side variable ? what do you want to accomplish ?

Comment: You'll have to have javascript set the value after the page loads. Alternatively, in the html, set the value to something constant and pick a url based on the value when you need it.

Comment: flagged as "not a real question", its dificult to tell if he wants the value inside it or insert a variable...

Comment: What's not to understand? I want to use a js variable in value="url1.com", obviously instead of url1.com

Comment: im not sure if its what i understand but: you cant use a js variable right with the html, what you can do is change it later after the html rendering, js is a executable language not a server-side like php

Comment: I know. How can I do what you have just described, using a js variable right with the html?

Comment: @Homie there are a couple of ways to do it, on body you can add the "onload" event, you can trigger using a "onchange" in the select

Answer (score 1):

Give your `option` field an id, like

```
<option id="option1" value="url1.com">Start Date</option>
```

Then you can easily set its value:

```
document.getElementById("option1").value = foo;
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment. However, I'd like to use a js variable inside the value attribute (value="url1.com" obviously instead of url1.com). Is it possible?

Comment: @Homie: No, that's not possible, you can only set a value after the markup is in the DOM. Alternatively, you can add the `option` element itself using JavaScript.

Comment: OK, finally I got an answer. It's not possible. Thanks Marcel!